# Multiple materials on subdivided face resulting in displacement

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, modifiers, faces

I subdivided a face to apply multiple materials to it. However after assigning them, they look displaced in edit and object mode, as well as in the rendered picture. What did I do wrong?
I tested multiple materials and all of them show the same behavior.

[image: Displacement in edit mode]
[image: Displacement in object mode]
I expected something like this:
[image]

What did I do wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Bevel modifier is subdividing the mesh again creating new face which are assigned to a certain material depending on there creation method , changing the number of segments to an even number will get you the desired result

Comment: nice catch.  It wasn't mentioned that the Bevel Modifier is being used.  :)